# Localhost refused to connect Xampp issue

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, localhost

i am trying to connect my site from others computers on local network. I can access the site from my system IP address but issue is this when i entered the username and password it will redirect the page from 192.168.0.2/ppp/login to localhost/ppp/auth/login and shows thee error localhost refused to connect.

Comment: have you changed all the URLs to ip address

Comment: yes i have changed the httpd.conf file and entered my static ip address

Comment: what? why there ? have you not changed url in your code,like static URL ,you must have mentioned somewhere?

Comment: i really dont know how to add static IP on my codes. i am new in this kindly tell me where to change the URL

Comment: haha you have to ask someone who know all code better OR you have to paste all your files here.Choice is yours

Comment: i am working in MVC framework and i checked again i haven't mention any URL's in my code

Comment: on which framework you are working?

Comment: i can access my login page from other computer but it will create issue when database is involved

Comment: tell me your framework name

Comment: Model-View-Controller (MVC)

Comment: is it custmized or like symfon,laravel , codeigniter etc

Comment: like means what ?if its framework then it must have config or constant file

Comment: actually i have buy this dashboard template which is made in MVC framework now i want to access this from other computers on network also

Comment: search for config or constant file

Comment: yes it has web.config file

Comment: give me the MVC link from which you have downloaded framework

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/stock-manager-advance-with-point-of-sale-module/5403161

Comment: irs paid ?.....

Comment: yes it is paid software

Comment: ohho.then I can not see code :(

Comment: Sorry I cant help anymore..

Answer (score 0):

localhost usually points to 127.0.0.1 . So, if you are getting redirected to localhost/login/ppp then the issue with your site's code. Don't redirect to http://localhost/login/ppp. Just do a redirect to /login/ppp instead.

The reason connection is refused is because the other PC doesn't have XAMPP (or any other web server) running on it.

Comment: so whats the solution?

Answer (score 0):

your only need to change the config.php file in controllers. write your IP instead of localhost. Your code will run properly on network.